# Graph permutation and it's Euclidean interpretation

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

In a paper by [Zou and Lerman](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1063520318300678), two examples of graph permutation that correspond to translation and rigid transformation are presented. The first example consists of a periodic lattice graph. It is shown that a given permutation $P$ corresponds to translation in the Euclidean domain.

[image]

This example is fairly reasonable and I don't have a problem with it. The authors furthermore give another example where a permutation $P$ would be interpreted as a rigid transformation.

[image]

Then the authors state that

> The comparison between Figs. a and c makes it clear that the graph
>   and signal permutation corresponds to a Euclidean rigid transformation
>   in the planar representation of the graph.

Unfortunately, this not very clear for me. In fact it is not clear at all. I was wondering if someone can shed some light on it. Thanks!